# Is this overfitting or underfitting on an XOR test?

Tags: c++, neural-network

I have the following Neural Network code, I'm just trying to work my way up from basic problems, such as the XOR problem, while building up a codebase. This is a hobby project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

typedef float DataType;
typedef DataType (*ActivationFuncPtr)(const DataType&);

static DataType learningRate = 0.02;
static std::size_t numberEpochs = 1000000;

DataType sigmoid(const DataType& x)
{
    return DataType(1) / (DataType(1) + std::exp(-x));
}

template<typename T>
class Random
{
public:
    T operator()()
    {
        return m_dis(m_mt);
    }

protected:
    static std::mt19937 m_mt;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<T> m_dis;
};

template<typename T> std::mt19937 Random<T>::m_mt(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());
template<typename T> std::uniform_real_distribution<T> Random<T>::m_dis(0,1);

template<std::size_t NumInputs>
class Neuron
{
public:

    Neuron(ActivationFuncPtr activationFunction)
    :
        m_activationFunction(activationFunction)
    {
        Random<DataType> r;
        std::generate(m_weights.begin(),m_weights.end(),[&]()
        {
            return r();
        });
        m_biasWeight = r();
    }

    void FeedForward(const std::array<DataType,NumInputs>& inputValues)
    {
        DataType sum = m_biasWeight;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < inputValues.size(); ++i)
            sum += inputValues[i] * m_weights[i];
        m_output = m_activationFunction(sum);

        m_netInput = sum;
    }

    DataType GetOutput() const
    {
        return m_output;
    }

    DataType GetNetInput() const
    {
        return m_netInput;
    }

    std::array<DataType,NumInputs> Backpropagate(const DataType& error,
                           const std::array<DataType,NumInputs>& inputValues,
                           std::array<DataType,NumInputs+1>& weightAdjustments)
    {
        DataType errorOverOutput = error;
        DataType outputOverNetInput = m_output * (DataType(1) - m_output); // sigmoid derivative

        std::array<DataType,NumInputs> netInputOverWeight;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
        {
            netInputOverWeight[i] = inputValues[i];
        }

        DataType netInputOverBias = DataType(1);

        std::array<DataType,NumInputs> errorOverWeight;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
        {
            errorOverWeight[i] = errorOverOutput * outputOverNetInput * netInputOverWeight[i];
        }

        DataType errorOverBias = errorOverOutput * outputOverNetInput * netInputOverBias;

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
        {
            weightAdjustments[i] = errorOverWeight[i];
        }
        weightAdjustments[NumInputs] = errorOverBias;

        DataType errorOverNetInput = errorOverOutput * outputOverNetInput;

        std::array<DataType,NumInputs> errorWeights;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
        {
            errorWeights[i] = errorOverNetInput * m_weights[i];
        }

        return errorWeights;
    }

    void AdjustWeights(const std::array<DataType,NumInputs+1>& adjustments)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
            m_weights[i] = m_weights[i] - learningRate * adjustments[i];
        m_biasWeight = m_biasWeight - learningRate * adjustments[NumInputs];
    }

    const std::array<DataType,NumInputs> GetWeights() const {return m_weights;}
    const DataType& GetBiasWeight() const { return m_biasWeight; }

protected:
    std::array<DataType,NumInputs> m_weights;
    DataType m_biasWeight;

    ActivationFuncPtr m_activationFunction;

    DataType m_output;
    DataType m_netInput;
};

main()
{

    std::array<std::array<DataType,2>,4> inputData = {{{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}}};
    std::array<std::array<DataType,1>,4> desiredOutputs = {{{0},{1},{1},{0}}};
    std::array<Neuron<2>*,2> hiddenLayer1 = {{ new Neuron<2>(sigmoid), new Neuron<2>(sigmoid) }};
    std::array<Neuron<2>*,1> outputLayer = {{ new Neuron<2>(sigmoid) }};

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(80);

    DataType minError = std::numeric_limits<DataType>::max();
    bool minErrorFound = false;

    std::size_t epochNumber = 0;
    while(epochNumber < numberEpochs && !minErrorFound)
    {
        DataType epochMSE = 0;

        for(std::size_t row = 0; row < inputData.size(); ++row)
        {
            const std::array<DataType,2>& dataRow = inputData[row];
            const std::array<DataType,1>& outputRow = desiredOutputs[row];

            // Feed the values through to the output layer

            hiddenLayer1[0]->FeedForward(dataRow);
            hiddenLayer1[1]->FeedForward(dataRow);

            DataType output0 = hiddenLayer1[0]->GetOutput();
            DataType output1 = hiddenLayer1[1]->GetOutput();

            outputLayer[0]->FeedForward({output0,output1});

            DataType finalOutput0 = outputLayer[0]->GetOutput();

            // if there was more than 1 output neuron these errors need to be summed together first to create total error
            DataType totalError = 0.5 * std::pow(outputRow[0] - finalOutput0,2.f);
            epochMSE += totalError * totalError;

            DataType propagateError = -(outputRow[0] - finalOutput0);

            std::array<DataType,3> weightAdjustmentsOutput;
            std::array<DataType,2> outputError = outputLayer[0]->Backpropagate(propagateError,
                                                                   {output0,output1},
                                                                   weightAdjustmentsOutput);

            std::array<DataType,3> weightAdjustmentsHidden1;
            hiddenLayer1[0]->Backpropagate(outputError[0],dataRow,weightAdjustmentsHidden1);

            std::array<DataType,3> weightAdjustmentsHidden2;
            hiddenLayer1[1]->Backpropagate(outputError[1],dataRow,weightAdjustmentsHidden2);

            outputLayer[0]->AdjustWeights(weightAdjustmentsOutput);
            hiddenLayer1[0]->AdjustWeights(weightAdjustmentsHidden1);
            hiddenLayer1[1]->AdjustWeights(weightAdjustmentsHidden2);
        }

        epochMSE *= DataType(1) / inputData.size();

        if(epochMSE >= minError + 0.00000001)
        {
            minErrorFound = true;
        }
        else
            minError = epochMSE;

        ++epochNumber;
    }

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(80)
                << "\n\n====================================\n"
                << "   TRAINING COMPLETE"
                << "\n\n====================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Minimum error: " << minError << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number epochs: " << epochNumber << "/" << numberEpochs << std::endl;

    // output tests
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
                << "\n\n====================================\n"
                << "   FINAL TESTS"
                << "\n\n====================================" << std::endl;

    for(std::size_t row = 0; row < inputData.size(); ++row)
    {
        const std::array<DataType,2>& dataRow = inputData[row];
        const std::array<DataType,1>& outputRow = desiredOutputs[row];
        std::cout << dataRow[0] << "," << dataRow[1] << " (" << outputRow[0] << ")  :  ";

        // Feed the values through to the output layer

        hiddenLayer1[0]->FeedForward(dataRow);
        hiddenLayer1[1]->FeedForward(dataRow);

        DataType output0 = hiddenLayer1[0]->GetOutput();
        DataType output1 = hiddenLayer1[1]->GetOutput();

        outputLayer[0]->FeedForward({output0,output1});

        DataType finalOutput0 = outputLayer[0]->GetOutput();

        std::cout << finalOutput0 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Most of the time, the output looks like this, and I think "great! success!"

```
====================================
   TRAINING COMPLETE

====================================
Minimum error: 0.00000000106923325748908837340422905981540679931640625000000000000000000000000000
Number epochs: 1000000/1000000


====================================
   FINAL TESTS

====================================
0.00,0.00 (0.00)  :  0.01
0.00,1.00 (1.00)  :  0.99
1.00,0.00 (1.00)  :  0.99
1.00,1.00 (0.00)  :  0.01

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.992 s
Press any key to continue.
```

But then the following is the output occassionally, which I want to understand, is this overfitting, or underfitting, or have I done something wrong somewhere? How can I prevent this?

```
====================================
   TRAINING COMPLETE

====================================
Minimum error: 0.00787912402302026748657226562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Number epochs: 1000000/1000000


====================================
   FINAL TESTS

====================================
0.00,0.00 (0.00)  :  0.01
0.00,1.00 (1.00)  :  0.50
1.00,0.00 (1.00)  :  0.99
1.00,1.00 (0.00)  :  0.50

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.024 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I have tried using more or less epochs along with a higher or lower learning rate, but I still ocassionally get a result as above (not always the exact same as above but similar). For example, with a learning rate of `0.002` and `1000000` epochs, I get the following ocassionally:

```
====================================
   TRAINING COMPLETE

====================================
Minimum error: 0.01417684461921453475952148437500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Number epochs: 176477/1000000


====================================
   FINAL TESTS

====================================
0.00,0.00 (0.00)  :  0.29
0.00,1.00 (1.00)  :  0.59
1.00,0.00 (1.00)  :  0.59
1.00,1.00 (0.00)  :  0.63

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.225 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I see how it exited early because the error grew rather than shrank, but is that because I exited early when I shouldn't have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done nothing wrong. Notice that you get different results even after training your network with the same amount of epochs and training data. Overfitting would be the cause if you would have used more epochs and/or training data in the network that works wrong. Underfitting is the opposite of that. You don't have underfitting, and you don't have overfitting. You could try to lower your learning rate by an order of magnitude or ar least by half, increase it, change training function or add momentum. It is important for you to know that neural networks is a very empirical process, if your trained network passes validation then it's ok, if not then tweak it a bit and retrain or just retrain. There is no closed form formula, solution or recipe for their design.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. I sort of thought that the XOR problem couldn't have local minima, only global minima? In any case, what else can I do?

Comment: I tried lowering the learning rate to both `0.002` and `0.01` but I get similar results still. Simliar meaning that sometimes it just doesn't classify correctly. When you say it's an empirical process etc, do you mean to say that sometimes your network just doesn't work (I assume because the random starting weights) and so you just need to try again? If so, surely there's a better way to initiate the weights. Could you double-check my backprop is correct?

Comment: By empirical I mean just that. Finding the optimal initial weight values is an open question. You're code works fine, I tested it. I ran several training sessions with the only difference being the weight values, got results like yours. It proves you don't have a problem, it's just the network being annoying as sometimes they are, even simple ones. Train one that gives correct results and keep it. Again, you have no issues.

Comment: in that case how does something like reinforcement learning work, or generative adversarial networks? For example, if I was unlucky to have bad initial weights in a network that I was using reinforcement learning, how would I ever know? In GAN, if one of the two networks had bad initial weights, wouldn't it invalidate everything they do?

Comment: Those type of networks are very different from the simple multilayer perceptron you designed. Short answer for reinforcement learning and GANs, you don't need to know if you had bad initial weights, and it does not invalidate anything they do, those networks modify the weights in a different way and according to a different criteria than just mere gradient descent. Think of them as providing a means of "self healing".